# how to change numbers in specific position inside list

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace, element

```
def id(id):
    num = [int(x) for x in str(id)]
    num[1] = num[1]*2
    num[3] = num[3]*2
    num[5] = num[5]*2
    num[7] = num[7]*2
    print(num)

x = id(123456789)
```

I've tried so many ways to write this code in a "professional way" but this is the only way i can make it work

Comment: What are you asking? I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "professional way"?

Comment: what are you trying do? Do you need to multiply by two in all even position string

Comment: You can change with help of index or even the desired number (you want to change)

Comment: after `print(num)` add `return num`  , then you will get that new values list into `x` variable

Comment: You're probably better off not calling your function `id` (which is a built-in function), and not calling your function parameter the same thing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong about the way you are doing things, if you just want to change the values at some particular positions. Of course, here there is a pattern which you can exploit:

```
for i in range(1, len(num), 2):
    num[i] *= 2
```

However, if the positions are arbitrary, the "professional" way is not to use magic numbers in the function, but something like:

```
POSITIONS = [1, 4, 5, 7]

def make_id(input_id): # don't shadow built-in names
    num = map(int, str(input_id))
    for i in POSITIONS:
        num[i] *= 2
    # return some value, don't just print it
    return int(''.join(map(str, num)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def multiply_even_indexes(number):
    # Going for each digit, and multiply by 2 if it's index is even
    # int(d)*2**(i % 2) means that we:
    # 1. Convert x to number
    # 2. Multiply x with 2 in the power of either 0 or 1 (depends if `i` is even)
    #    That means:
    #    For i = 1: We get i%2==1 (reminder of 1) so it's multiply by 2^1=2 (so we multiply by two the second element)
    #    For i = 2: We get i%2==0 (mo reminder) so it's multiply by 2^0=1 (so we don't change the third element)
    digits_result = [int(d)*2**(i % 2) for i, d in enumerate(str(number))]
    return digits_result 

x = multiply_even_indexes(123456789)

# [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9]
print(x)
```